# HTML 5 Audio API Sound Dosent Pause Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

Hello I'm trying to figure out why certain elements arent pausing correctly. I've been trying to figure this simple error for awhile. I have a click event on a audio tag and when I play the audio, I would like to pause it, which works perfectly, Buttt.. when I press the audio tag again, it starts from the beginning of the audio file, and it should have left off where I paused it at. My code snippet is below...My guess is that my src attribute is resending a brand new request to the server everytime I click on pause, and it shouldnt.. (Hence the data is an object of mp3's that i'm looping through) So if anyone could help me fix this quick issue, that'll be great!!! ...

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <audio id="audio"></audio>
    <div id="btnPlay">Play</div>
    <div id="btnPause">Pause</div>
<div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("btnPlay").onclick = function (e) {
    var player = document.getElementById("audio");
    player.src = "admin/" + "admin_data/" + "member_sounds/" + obj["sounds_name"];
    player.play();
};

document.getElementById("btnPause").onclick = function (e) {
    var player = document.getElementById("audio");
    player.pause();
};
```

Comment: Just use <audio controls>

Comment: @i want to customize the audio controls.... Im dynamically creating the controls

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? I think browser defaults are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If happens because when you hit play button you are setting the source which will invoke a new load operation in some browsers and reset the start position (and the only reason why you can play is that the file is loaded from cache as the loading is asynchronous).

Try by setting the src outside your play button:

```
var player = document.getElementById("audio");
player.preload = 'auto';

/// you should really add a canplay event handler here...

player.src = "admin/" + "admin_data/" + "member_sounds/" + obj["sounds_name"];

document.getElementById("btnPlay").onclick = function (e) {
    player.play();
};
```

Comment: @ Ken, thanks, works perfectly!, you were right i was invoking a new load every time the play element was clicked on..